Do the Möbius Transformations $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ and $z \mapsto 1 - z$ generate a finite group?
I have been given an exercise that asks me to show that $f:z \mapsto \frac1z$ and $g:z \mapsto 1 - z$ generate a finite group.
My first approach was to look associated matrices
$$F = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad
G = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix},$$
These matrices do not commute, and I’ve found that $F^2 = G^2 = I$ (The identity matrix). I also computed that $(FG)^6 = (GF)^6 = I$. Based on these observations, I suspect that the group generated by $F$ and $G$ might be the dihedral group $D_6$.
However, I’m unsure how to formally prove this or even how to show that the group generated by these matrices is finite without constructing the full composition table.
Is there a concise, rigorous argument that I can use to prove that these matrices generate the group $D_6$, or at least demonstrate that they generate a finite group?

A Möbius transformation is uniquely determined by its action on $3$ points. In this case, the natural points to look at are $0$, $1$, and $\infty$. That's because both transformations you start with have nice behavior on these three points:

$z \mapsto \frac1z$ swaps $0$ and $\infty$ while leaving $1$ fixed.
$z \mapsto 1-z$ swaps $0$ and $1$ while leaving $\infty$ fixed.

It follows that compositions of these transformations also induce a permutation of $\{0, 1, \infty\}$, showing that the group is finite (because there is only one Möbius transformation for each possible permutation). Also, the finite group is isomorphic to $S_3$, because $S_3$ is generated by two transpositions. ($S_3$ is isomorphic to the $6$-element dihedral group, so your guess is correct.)

First, calculate $$C:=G\cdot F=\left[\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\right].$$ Then it can be shown that $F^{-1}\cdot C\cdot F=C^{-1}$, which shows that the group $\langle F,G\rangle$ is indeed $D_3$ (or $D_6$, depending on which notation you prefer).
Small remark: Since you are interested in the Möbius transformations, you need to calculate the order of $C$ as an element of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})/Z(\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}))$, which is 3 and not $6$.

Finding all the elements of the group generated by $f$ and $g$ is not terribly challenging.
$g\circ f(z)=\dfrac{z-1}z$.
$f\circ g(z)=\dfrac1{1-z}$.
$f\circ g\circ f(z)=g\circ f\circ g(z)=\dfrac z{z-1}$.
Also note that $f\circ g\circ f\circ g(z)=g\circ f(z)$ and $g\circ f\circ g\circ f(z)=f\circ g(z)$.
So this is a finite group with elements $e, f, g, gf, fg,$ and $fgf$.
Since $f\circ f(z)=g\circ g(z)=z$, no other elements can be generated.

Since the group has order $6$ with three elements of order $2$ ($f, g, $ and $fgf$) and two elements of order $3$ ($gf$ and $fg$), it's the dihedral group

You can prove the group has order at most $6$ by using the relators $f^2,fcfc^2$, where $c: \equiv fg.$  (The second relator gives anti-commutativity.)
Then it's straight forward to display $6$ distinct elements.
Finally there are only two groups of order $6,$ namely $S_3=D_3$ and $C_6.$
But it is not cyclic.

Huge Home Run equals Not Wrong
